# How to pass Viewstate value from one aspx page to another page?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

Actually, I'm using viewstate for sending value from one page to another. Can we do it like this? If yes, then how? I only wanted to with viewstate, not other techniques like cookie or querystring.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use only viewstate  to send data to next page, then you should use the `server.transfer()` method instead of `resposnse.redirect()` method. Let us suppose we want to pass `viewstate` on click of a button as below:

```
    public void btnSer_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ViewState["yourvalue"] = "Name";
        ViewState["yourcity"] = "Shimla";
        Server.Transfer("Default.aspx");

    }
```

on the same page create a method of the class statebag

```
     public StateBag ReturnViewState()
    {
        return ViewState;
    }
```

Now on the page where you want to transfer let here be Default.aspx. Place the following function in Default.aspx.cs file

```
private StateBag PreviousPageViewState
    {
        get
        {
            StateBag returnValue = null;
            if (PreviousPage != null)
            {
                Object objPreviousPage = (Object)PreviousPage;
                MethodInfo objMethod = objPreviousPage.GetType().GetMethod("ReturnViewState");//System.Reflection class
                return (StateBag)objMethod.Invoke(objPreviousPage, null);

            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
```

Now let us find the values of `viewstate` of previous page( `ViewState["yourvalue"]` and `ViewState["yourcity"]`)

let us do it at page load of Default.aspx

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PreviousPage != null && PreviousPageViewState != null)
        {
            var sg = PreviousPageViewState["yourvalue"].ToString();
            var nev = PreviousPageViewState["yourcity"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

So we are done. you can access the `viewstate` value of previous page.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve data form previous page in three ways.

**PostBackUrl**

On your first page/form (First.aspx.cs) create a public property with the listbox:

```
public TextBox PostedTextBox { get { return TextBox1; } }
```

Set the postback-url for the button to Second.aspx

Second page in the aspx-file after the @Page-directive add:

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/First.aspx" %>
```

Then in Form_Load on Second.aspx.cs you can extract the values:

```
if (PreviousPage != null)
{
    TextBox postedTextBox = PreviousPage.PostedTextBox;
    //...
}
```

**Locate control/data using PreviousPage**

You could locate the control by using:

```
if (PreviousPage != null)
{
  var control = PreviousPage.FindControl("ListBox1") as ListBox;
}
```

**Request form-data**

You could use GetValues:

```
Request.Form.GetValues("ctl00$MainContent$ListBox1");
```

returns a string array containing each of the selected items.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is working with cross page postbacks by adding a `PostBackUrl` to your button.  Let's say we post from page A to page B. You can subscribe A's button's `Click` event and populate a public property of A:

```
MyPublicProperty = ViewState["MyInfo"];
```

You can use `Page.PreviousPage` in B now to access A's `MyPublicProperty`. Just check `PreviousPage` for null and cast it to A's type.

I know this does not literally transfer the viewstate, and I'm not too happy with having this solution in some of my code to be honest, but it is a way to cross-posting viewstate information.

Comment: yes this is quit right answer ,i just get few answers they all are related to properties..i think using property is the best solution.thanks for your interest......

Comment: Yeah, it enables you to introduce an common interface with the properties, if you'd like to cross-post from multiple pages. MatteKarla's solution is maybe more straightforward in simple scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

**"Viewstate is useful with in the page only"**. if you want to maintain with in the pages then use **"Session"**

ex: in c#

```
Session["name"] ="the value that maintain";
```

Comment: True. However, even though Frank explicitly mentions he will not use query string, I'd perhaps prefer it over the Session state. Session state has a broader scope than just "A to B". For instance, if a user is working with multiple browser tabs, transfers are interfering with each other.

Answer (score 0):

1. create a public property on the source page that returns the viewstate value.

e.g.:

```
namespace MyNameSpace

{ 

    public class SourcePageClassName

     {
        public string MyValue

        {

            get

            {

                 if ( this.ViewState("MyViewStateValue") == null )

                 {

                     this.ViewState("MyViewStateValue") = "default value";

                 }

                 return this.ViewState("MyViewStateValue").ToString();

             }

             set

             {

                 this.ViewState("MyViewStateValue") = value;

             }
        }

    }
} 

2. do a Server.Transfer to the destination page.

e.g.:

Server.Transfer("Destination.aspx")

3.  On the destination page, on the page load event, I check whether the Context.Current.Handler is of the type of the source page and if it's then I cast it and read the property

e.g.:

...

protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)

{ 

    if ( Context.Current.Handler != null && Context.Current.Handler.GetType() == typeof(SourcePageClassName) )

    {

        SourcePageClassName source = Context.Current.Handler as SourcePageClassName;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(source.MyValue);

    }

}
```

and that's it...

on ASP.NET 2.0 you can do the same thing or do a cross postback creating the property I mentioned on step 1

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the ViewState of one form from another form directly.

But we can pass the value in the Context collection and then access the value in another page.

Form1:

```
Context.Items.Add ( "MyVar" , ViewState["yourvalue"].ToString() );
```

Form2:

```
string myValue = Context.Items["MyVar"].ToString();
```

Comment: @Sanoop don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms.